# Is there no way to determine if a file is hidden or not?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have been looking for a way to know the status of `Hidden` attribute of `StorageFile` object. As far as I have read the docs, the `FileAttributes` property does not have the `Hidden` attribute. Any workaround?

Comment: Did you really look at the [`FileAttributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation? `Hidden` is pretty clearly defined...

Comment: @RonBeyer are they really defined for `UWP` ? Have a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.fileattributes  No attribute for hidden files.

Comment: Yes, you can use [`File.GetAttributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getattributes(v=vs.110).aspx) to get it, at the bottom of the page it says that it is supported in UWP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two file access APIs in UWP. The newer one, built for UWP is `Windows.Storage`, which includes `StorageFile` as you mentioned. This is specifically built for this sandboxed scenario where the app has limited access to the filesystem. In this case, the `Hidden` attribute is really not available and `Hidden` files are even not listed when calling `StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync()` etc. The main advantage of `Storage` APIs is that they are built as asynchronous and that they can cover scenarios like user picked folder - to which you then get a temporary permission by virtue of the specific `StorageFolder` instance.

The second API set is the old and trusted `System.IO` file API, that provides a lot more control and includes the control over `Hidden` attribute. The disadvantage is that by default you can access only the app's install and AppData locations with this API, unless your app declares the Broad file system access API or App alias, which are new features in Windows 10 April 2018 update and later.

Comment: There are more than two APIs :-). Don't forget Win32, CRT and STL at a minimum... plus any other frameworks you might care to use like Boost.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find a solution that works for UWP storage files, that are not necessarily located in a known directory (such as app folder, downloads, pictures etc.).

For known directories you can create a new instance of FileInfo with the path of the file, and its attributes property will tell you whether the file is hidden or not.
Unfortunately, this solution won't apply for files outside of the known directories, as asking for the attributes of the FileInfo instance will throw an unauthorized access exception (or something similar).

I did find a solution that works for checking the hidden attribute for files located in various parts of the file system, assuming you have access to the requested file's StorageFile object:

```
public bool isHidden(StorageFile file) {
  var extendedFileAttributes = "System.FileAttributes";
  uint hiddenAttributeValue = (uint) FileAttributes.Hidden;
  IDictionary<string, object> retrievedProperties =
    await file.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(new List<string> { extendedFileAttributes });
  var attributes = retrievedProperties[extendedFileAttributes];
  if (attributes != null)
  {
      return (((uint)attributes & hiddenAttributeValue) == hiddenAttributeValue));
  }
  return false;
}
```

Retrieving extended file properties:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-getting-file-properties

Strings to retrieve:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/core-bumper